# Show/hide select options using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have three identical selects.I want to remove or add the options in each based on what is chosen already so that you can only choose what is left.What I tried

```
<div id="myselects">
<select class="e1" style="width:300px">
        <option></option>
        <option >Alabama</option>
        <option >Amalapuram</option>
        <option >Anakapalli</option>
       </select>

<select class="e1" style="width:300px">
        <option></option>
        <option >Alabama</option>
        <option >Amalapuram</option>
        <option >Anakapalli</option>
       </select>

<select class="e1" style="width:300px">
        <option></option>
        <option >Alabama</option>
        <option >Amalapuram</option>
        <option >Anakapalli</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

script

```
$('.e1').change(function(){
 var value=$(this).find('option:selected').val();


 $('#myselects').find('option[value="'+ value +'"]:not(:selected)').attr('disabled','disabled');


});
```

Comment: your options doesn't have any values

Comment: Please explain: you need,1) three select 2) if user choose some option in first select then  this option should be removed from other two select. Am I right? if not then please explain by adding some more words to your question

Comment: Yes this is what I need.When the user clicks the selects only options not chosen in other selects will be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have no value attribute on your options this won't work. When you get the .val() of the first select it will return the "computed" value which is either the selected option's value attribute OR the "text" value of the option (which is what you will get)... however when you try to filter the other options by their value attribute... they will all be empty.

However this should work as it compares the `text()` vs. the val():

```
$('.e1').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    if(value != ''){
        $('#myselects').find('option:not(:selected)').each(function(){
            if($(this).text() == value){
                //uncomment if you want to disable
                //$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');

                //remove this option
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You can try it out in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vpjs6bj/)

Comment: Thank you but I thought disabling would remove the option from view.Is there a way to remove or hide them?

Comment: Yes if you want to you can hide it. e.g. `$(this).hide();` or you can remove it. `$(this).remove();`

Comment: I notice once it is removed it cannot be shown again if not selected also it also removes the empty option which I need.

Comment: I've updated the code so that it doesn't alter the other select lists unless a non-blank option is selected. It now removes the option vs. disabling it (though the code option to disable is there, just uncomment). If you want the options to "come back" if the user changes selections then maybe disabling is better than removing.

Comment: That's the thing I do want them to enable once the are not selected in any of the checkboxes. so I think disabling them is better but when I tried putting the enable in the same change function the list did not update

Comment: Ok, this gets more complicated... you're going to need to keep track of which items have been selected outside of the 3 select lists.